# Swift - Cannot subscript a value type [String] with an index type of NSNumber?

Tags: arrays, swift, uibutton, uiimage

I am trying to get assign an image's name to a button. The image name is stored in an array. However I am getting the error in the title

My code:

```
//profilePic is the button
//friend is a coredata object received from another view. picIndex is stored as int16 in the coredata

profilePic.setImage(UIImage(named: imgArray[friend.picIndex]), forState: UIControlState.Normal);
```

My Array:

```
var imgArray = ["a.jpg", "aq3d.jpg", "b.jpg", "c.jpg", "d.jpg", "e.jpg", "f.jpg",
    "fallout.jpg", "g.jpg", "h.jpg", "i.jpg", "j.jpg", "k.jpg", "overwatch.jpg", "space.jpg"];
```

Comment: OT: You don´t need the `;` in Swift.

Comment: Is `friend.picIndex` an `NSNumber`?

Comment: @RashwanL Yeah I know. But I wanna keep using it because I do other languages too. Its a habit

Comment: @rmaddy picIndex is int16

Answer (score 0):

Swift requires you to "unwrap" `NSNumber` in this context by calling `intValue`:

```
profilePic.setImage(
    UIImage(named: imgArray[friend.picIndex.intValue])
,   forState: UIControlState.Normal //     ^^^^^^^^^
)
```

If you have control over the class of `friend` variable, consider making `picIndex` an `Int` instead of `NSNumber`.